# What are the pros and cons of replacing a list of conditionals(if/switch/ternary operators) with a predicate list?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, predicate

Recently I've come across with a school of thought that advocates **replacing conditionals(if/switch/ternary operators, same below) with something else**(polymorphism, strategy, visitor, etc).

As I'd like to learn by trying new approaches, I've then revised some of my Javascript codes and immediately found a relevant case, which is basically the following list of ifs(which is essentially the same as a switch/nested ternary operators):

```
function checkResult(input) {
    if (isCond1Met(input)) return result1;
    if (isCond2Met(input)) return result2;
    if (isCond3Met(input)) return result3;
    // More conditionals here...
    if (isCondNMet(input)) return resultN;
    return defaultResult;
};
```

Shortly after I've come up with trying a predicate list instead.

Assuming that checkResult always return a String(which applies to my specific case), the above list of ifs can be replaced with a list of predicates(it uses arrow function and find which are ES6+ features though):

```
var resultConds = {
    result1: isCond1Met,
    result2: isCond2Met,
    result3: isCond3Met,
    // More mappings here...
    resultN: isCondNMet
};
var results = Object.keys(resultConds);

function checkResult(input) {
    return results.find(result => resultConds[result](input)) || defaultResult;
};
```

(On a side note: Whether checkResult should take resultConds and defaultResult as arguments should be a relatively minor issue here, same below)

If the above assumption doesn't hold, the list of predicates can be changed into this instead:

```
var conds = [
    isCond1Met,
    isCond2Met,
    isCond3Met,
    // More predicates here...
    isCondNMet
];
var results = [
    result1,
    result2,
    result3,
    // More results here...
    resultN
];

function checkResult(input) {
    return results[conds.findIndex(cond => cond(input))] || defaultResult;
};
```

A bigger refactoring maybe this:

```
var condResults = {
    cond1: result1,
    cond2: result2,
    cond3: result3,
    // More mappings here...
    condN: resultN,
};
var conds = Object.keys(condResults);

function checkResult(input) {
    return condResults[conds.find(cond => isCondMet[cond](input))] || defaultResult;
};
```

I'd like to ask what're the pros and cons(**preferably with relevant experience and explanations**) of replacing a list of conditionals with a predicate list, **at least in such cases**(e.g.: input validation check returning a non boolean result based on a list of conditionals)?

For instance, which approach generally leads to probably better:

- Testability(like unit testing)
- Scalability(when there are more and more conditionals/predicates)
- Readability(for those being familiar with both approaches to ensure sufficiently fair comparisons)
- Usability/Reusability(avoiding/reducing code duplications)
- Flexibility(for example, when the internal lower level logic for validating inputs changes drastically while preserving the same external higher level behavior)
- Memory footprint/Time performance(specific to Javascript)
- Etc

Also, if you think the predicate list approach can be improved, please feel free to demonstrate the pros and cons of that improved approach.

Edit: As @Bergi mentioned that Javascript objects are unordered, the ES6+ Maps may be a better choice :)

Comment: Notice that javascript objects are not ordered. If your predicates rely on a certain order they need to be applied in, you have to put them in an array.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that, so it seems to me that, to play safe, I'll better be using the 2 array setup if a predicate list's to be used.

Comment: The primary value of the predicate list approach is that it can be altered or adapted at runtime. This flexibility comes at the expense of some additional complexity and some performance expenses as there is some small amount of additional code & function dispatch. If your predicates are themselves at all complex, the performance impact is likely de minimis. The exact performance impact you can answer for yourself by benchmarking the versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, putting business logic (like these predicates) in separate objects always improves testability, scalability, readability, maintainability and reusability. This comes from the modularisation inherent to this OOP design, and allows you to keep these predicates in a central store and apply whatever business procedures you want on them, staying independent from your codebase. Essentially, you're treating those conditions **as data**. You can even choose them dynamically, transform them to your liking, and work with them on an abstract layer.

Readability might suffer when you need to go to certain lengths to replace a simple a short condition with the generic approach, but it pays of well if you have many predicates.

Flexibility for adding/changing/removing predicates improves a lot, however the flexibility to choose a different architecture (how to apply which kind of predicates) will worsen - you cannot just change the code in one small location, you need to touch every location that uses the predicates.

Memory and performance footprints will be bigger as well, but not enough to matter.

Regarding scalability, it only works when you choose a good architecture. A list of rules that needs to be applied in a linear fashion might not do any more at a certain size.

Comment: Can I summarize your answer this way?
"Moving business logics from codes to data will generally lead to higher code qualities."

Comment: I would say "…enables better abstraction". Whether that *potential* is actually used to implement a higher code quality is a different question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am very much a noob at this, and regarding readabillity and usabillity I prefer the latter but it's a personal preference and I'm usually backwards so you shouldn't listen to me.
The conditional approach is more portable, I mean easily ported to non-object oriented languages. But that may never happen, and even if it does the people doing that kinds of things probably has tools and experience so it shouldn't be an issue. Regarding performance I doubt there will be any significant differences, first one looks like branching and second kind of like random access.
But as I said, you shouldn't listen to me as I'm just guessing

Comment: I'm thinking of function pointers(C as an example) when you mentioned "ported to non-object oriented languages" :)